# Freeswitch set variable using Perl

Tags: perl, parsing, variables, freeswitch

There is a dialplan that bridges the incoming call to three users in a round robin fashion.

It makes a webservice request using curl as follows :

```
<action application="curl" data ="http://10.0.0.90:3081/routecall?number='${caller_id_number}' " inline="true" />
```

The curl service adds the number of the caller as get param and returns following parameters separated by a special character "-" :

Ex : Tonny_Stark-1002-1003-1005

- Display Name of caller (Tonny_Stark)
- The first client to be bridged (1002)
- The second client to be bridged (1003)
- The third client to be bridged (1005)

I have to parse this response into different variables and pass it to the bridge action. 
I have written the Perl script for parsing as follows :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl5.8.8

$curl_response= $ARGV[0]; // The response from webservice.
$param_name = $ARGV[1] ;  // The parameter that is needed.

@params = split(/-/, $curl_response);


print  getParamValue();



sub getParamValue(){

if($param_name eq  "display_name")
{

  return $params[0];
}
elsif($param_name eq "first_cce")
{

  return $params[1];
}
elsif($param_name eq "second_cce")
{

  return $params[2];
}


}
```

The call to this perl script is made as follows :

```
  <action application ="perl" data= "firstcce.pl '${curl_response_data}' 'first_cce'}" />
```

Need the response from the perl script to the bridge action :

```
<action application="bridge" data="{sip_contact_user ='${display_name_from_perl}'} [myid=bridge1]user/${first_cce_from_perl} | [myid=bridge2]user/${second_cce_from_perl}"/>
```

**But don't know how the perl script will return the values and assign it to the variables, which can be used in the bridge action. **

Comment: Please provide a reason for down-vote

Comment: You got down voted, because it's unclear what you want. You give `Perl`, but I don't see any Perl. You don't explain what that line where the data comes from, what the data looks like, or what your Perl script does.

Comment: The response from webservice along with which parameter is needed is passed to the perl script as extra arguments. The script spilts the above response into array. Don't know how it will return a value and assign to a variable in freeswitch

Comment: Have added the required information. Please suggest a way forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it. Answering my own question.

Declare a variable in dial-plan.

```
<variable name="var_name" value =""/>
```

Access it from Perl script :

```
 $session->setVariable("var_name",  $value);
```

Modified the Perl Script as follows :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl5.8.8

$curl_response= $ARGV[0];

@params = split(/-/, $curl_response);

getParamValue();


sub getParamValue(){

 $session->setVariable("display_name",  $params[0]);

 $session->setVariable("first_cce", $params[1]);

 $session->setVariable("second_cce",$params[2]);

 $session->setVariable("third_cce" , $params[3]);   


}
1;
```

Thanks.